# What makes adding block comments feature in Python so difficult/ unachievable?

Tags: python, comments

As you know C language allows multiline comments between the symbols `/*` and `*/`.

However, there is no such feature in Python. The closest thing is using *triple quotes* like:

```
"""
Multiline
Comment-alike
in Python
"""
```

which is not a true comment. Instead, we just define a string that is not assigned to a variable. I guess this takes some space in the final code unlike single line comments following `#` symbol.

Python is being updated regularly, and we occasionally end up with very original and innovative usage of syntax. My question is what makes adding block comments so difficult in Python by an update? Why no Python developer gets themselves bothered with it?

---

**EDIT** *on if multiline comments take space in the final bytecode:*

I have modified the same code to see if adding multiline comments affect the size of the final bytecode. `py_compile` module is used.

pkg.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print("TEST")
```

pkg.py (comments added):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print("TEST") 
"""
Here is a multiline
comment to check
if it affects the
size of the final bytecode.
"""
```

The result is that the latter code (with the triple quote comment) is 117 bytes while the original one is 115 bytes. Obviously, the comment string is not fully included in the final bytecode. Still, we cannot say multiline comments in Python have no effect on the size of the final code.

*Note that single line comments by the symbol `#` did not increase the size of the final bytecode at all.*

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say there might be two reasons:
1. The community of Python has its own particularities and they might have taken the decision to keep things as it is maybe due to keep compatibility with old systems?
2. Implementing again a piece of the compiler to tackle this issue might not be that simple too.
Anyway I've had this question with some pythonists before, I actually see no harm in keeping this as it is.

Comment: Multi-line strings that aren't in the position to be interpreted as docstrings generate no code. They are effectively multi-line comments.

Comment: define true comment?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Which is not reflected into final code, i.e. which does not occupy space in the final code, as it has no function other than informing the coder/ developer.

Comment: can you share the stats where this string which is not assigned to any object (comment) how much space is taking in the final code ?